# Parallel tasks in .NET Core Windows Service hang after a few seconds

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, backgroundworker, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to get a Windows Service running. The service should use a worker object to spawn multiple tasks.

I use `SemaphoreSlim` in both the worker object and each task to wait for events to finish, like so:

```
public static IHostBuilder ConfigureServices(this IHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<WorkerService>();
        services.AddSingleton<WorkerClient>();
    });

    return builder;
}
```

WorkerService

```
public WorkerService(ILogger<WorkerService> logger, WorkerClient workerClient)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _workerClient = workerClient;
    _bleClient.OnValuesReceived += _bleClient_OnValuesReceived;
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            await _workerClient.Run();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical(ex, "Error while running worker client.");
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_scanDelay), stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

WorkerClient

```
public class WorkerClient
{
    private Scanner _scanner;
    private SemaphoreSlim _lock;

    public WorkerClient()
    {
        _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
        _scanner = new Scanner();
        _scanner.OnScanFinished += scanner_ScanFinished;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        _scanner.Scan();
        await _lock.WaitAsync();
    }

    private void scanner_ScanFinished(object sender, string[] macs)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach(var mac in macs)
        {   
            var client = new TaskRunner(mac);
            tasks.Add(client.Run());
        }
        if(tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                var task = Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
                await task;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            }
        }
        _lock.Release();
    }
}
```

TaskRunner

```
public class TaskRunner
{
    private SemaphoreSlim _lock;
    private Client _client;

    public TaskRunner(string mac)
    {
        _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
        _client = new Client(mac);
        _client.OnWorkFinished += client_WorkFinished;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        _client.DoWork();
        await _lock.WaitAsync();
    }

    private void client_WorkFinished(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        _lock.Release();
    }
}
```

This whole construct runs fine when I launch it in a console or inside VS. But it hangs after 1-2 runs when I create a service using `sc` utility and start it.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong as I am very new to Windows Services and multithreading.

Comment: Just some advice. Dropping a code wall makes it difficult to notice the code below the fold. Try breaking it up so those reading can easily see the different areas/classes involved.

Comment: As a side note, you could replace the line `while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)` with `while(true)`, to have a consistent canceling behavior. Let the `Task.Delay` do the cancellation job!

Answer (score 0):

The `SemaphoreSlim` is probably not an adequate mechanism for converting an event to a `Task`, because it can't propagate exceptions. The [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1) class is a more suitable mechanism for this purpose. Also when subscribing to an event it is a good idea to unsubscribe when we don't want to receive any further notifications. Unsubscribing is achieved using the [`-=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/subtraction-operator#delegate-removal) operator.

Here are two extension methods for the classes `Scanner` and `Client`, that allow to subscribe to their specific events for a single notification, and propagate this notification as a `Task`.

```
public static class ScannerExtensions
{
    public static Task<string[]> ScanAsync(this Scanner source)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string[]>();
        Action<object, string[]> evenHandler = null;
        evenHandler = (s, macs) =>
        {
            source.OnScanFinished -= evenHandler;
            tcs.TrySetResult(macs);
        };
        source.OnScanFinished += evenHandler;
        try
        {
            source.Scan();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            source.OnScanFinished -= evenHandler;
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}

public static class ClientExtensions
{
    public static Task DoWorkAsync(this Client source)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        EventHandler evenHandler = null;
        evenHandler = (s, e) =>
        {
            source.OnWorkFinished -= evenHandler;
            tcs.TrySetResult(null);
        };
        source.OnWorkFinished += evenHandler;
        try
        {
            source.DoWork();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            source.OnWorkFinished -= evenHandler;
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

You could use the extension methods `Scanner.ScanAsync` and `Client.DoWorkAsync` to refactor the `ExecuteAsync` method of your service like this:

```
private Scanner _scanner = new Scanner();

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Task delayTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_scanDelay), token);
        try
        {
            string[] macs = await _scanner.ScanAsync();
            Task[] doWorktasks = macs.Select(mac =>
            {
                var client = new Client(mac);
                return client.DoWorkAsync();
            }).ToArray();
            await Task.WhenAll(doWorktasks);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
        }
        await delayTask;
    }
}
```

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but I think that it is a change in the right direction.

If the problem persists you could try creating and awaiting the `client.DoWorkAsync` tasks one at a time (instead of launching all of them concurrently), to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I updated the answer by simplifying the extension methods API. The callback is not needed.